# Modify or create different ployline for graph-hopper

Tags: openstreetmap, graphhopper

Good day i am rather new to osm navigation. I like the graphhopper library however i wish to modify the route as the user traverses with a winking indicator in real time. How can be approach.

Comment: What is a 'winking indicator'? Do you mean turn instructions in real time? You can use InstructionList.find

Comment: Yes that's correct navigation instructions in real time.  For example person x  traverses to location y, as person x walks the icon updates the position and erase the path line taken before. in real time?